# Ajax call is returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Html**

```
<div>
    <select id="method">
        <option value="get">GET</option>
        <option value="post">POST</option>
        <option value="put">PUT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="sendRequest()" />
    <span id='value1'>(Result)</span>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        // TODO: Replace with the URL of your WebService app
        var serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:99999/api/books';

        function sendRequest() {
            var method = $('#method').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: serviceUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#value1').text(data);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

The `success` function is showing up with arrays of [object, Object]. The console shows the data for each object, but it is not showing on the page.

For each book, I have to list the Id, Title, and the Author.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            IQueryable<BookDTO> books;
            books = from b in db.Books
                    select new BookDTO()
                    {
                        Id = b.Id,
                        Title = b.Title,
                        AuthorName = b.Author.Name
                    };
            return Ok(books);
```

[console.log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzzq.png)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Because you're converting the objects into strings...

Comment: Quick solution: `$('#value1').text(JSON.stringify(data));`.

Comment: The `console.log(data)` shows an Array of 4 objects. Each one has fields like Author, Id, Title. When I do `$('#value1').text(data[0].Id)`, it shows the first Id of the first object. I just don't know how to parse all the objects.

Comment: @StraightUp use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over the object

Comment: Thanks trincot, I was doing `JSON.parse(data)` but it gave me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you now know that `data` is an array, you can use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through it.

You'd have to modify your html to give the container `<div>` an `id` to target and exclude the first `<span>` element .

You could then append an HTML element at each iteration containing the data for each element in the `data` array:

```
<div id="container">
  <select id="method"> 
    <option value="get">GET</option> 
    <option value="post">POST</option> 
    <option value="put">PUT</option> 
  </select> 
  <input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="sendRequest()" /> 
  <!--- <span id='value1'>(Result)</span> remove because these can be added dynamically --->
</div>
```

Then your success callback would look like:

```
success: function (data) { 
  data.forEach(function(dataObj, index){
    var id = dataObj.Id,
      title = dataObj.Title,
      author  = dataObj.AuthorName;

    // Target div.container and append a span for every element in the data array
    $('#container').append(
      '<span>' +
        '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' +
        '<p>' + author + '</p>' +
      '</span>'
    ); 
  });
}
```

Comment: When I do it the way you have demonstrated, it gives me just one book name, not all of them.

Comment: Please update your question providing the actual log of what `data` is.

Comment: My solution should work if `data` is an array with four objects as you state.  Pleases update your question providing the actual log of what `data` is.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the `console.log.(data)`. I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by actual log of `data`?

Comment: You notice that the span that's being appended has no id on it...

Comment: Yes, I added the id, but everything is showing up undefined.

Comment: Did you copy and paste? If so there were a couple of back-ticks where there should have been a single quotes in my solution. I've updated it now

Comment: no, I typed with the single quotes. I just get a Undefined for everything on the page. But my console shows the actual objects.

Comment: I've amended my code to use the keys from your object, `AuthorName`, `Id` and `Title` respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#value1').text(data);
```

That is a whole object you are setting as a text.

Probably you should want to look in to what `data` variable have and then append those values from that as text.

Comment: @Satpal It's quite clear that the data is an `Object` from the description and the result.

Comment: Still you could have waited a bit longer and provided complete solution

Comment: @Satpal Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, the reason you are seeing this is because assigning the `data` object to a text value. Since the object is not a string, `Object.prototype.toString()` is invoked which displays the string representation of the object, or `"[object Object]"`.

Place a `debugger` statement and open your browser's development console / inspector and reload the page. Execution will halt at the location of the statement allowing you to interactively explore the object and figure out which fields are fit for display (e.g. if the `data` object contained information about a person, you would discover `data.name` and assign that to the element instead).

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#value1').text(data);
    debugger;
    console.log(data);
},
```